# O(n) vs O(nlogn) Time Complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I came across this time complexity example online, and am slightly confused.

```
x = n
while ( x > 0 ) {
    y = x
    while ( y > 0 ) {
        y = y - 1
    }
    x = x / 2
 }
```

The answer is stated as O(n). I am wondering why it is not O(nlogn). The reason why I say this is because the outer loop looks to be logarithmic, while the inner loop appears to be linear. If y=n (instead of x), would the time complexity THEN be O(nlogn)? If so, why?

Comment: It's both O(n) and O(n log n), but BigTheta(n): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How many time does it pass on `y=y-1`? That will measure the complexity, right?

- When x=n, it passes n times.
- When x=n/2, it passes n/2 times.
- When x=n/4, it passes n/4 times.
- ...

So it passes n + n/2 + n/4... which sum up to 2n.

Thus total complexity is O(n).

Don't be fooled, inner loop is linear but not independently from the outer loop.

Answer (score 5):

The inner loop is indeed linear, but each iteration does not take `n` steps, but `x` steps for the current value of `x` which is iteratively halved, which means that a finer analysis is possible. You have over-estimated the cost of the inner loop. Consequently, the bound

```
O(n log n)
```

is also correct, but

```
O(n)
```

is a smaller bound. The smaller bound can be seen by reasoning that the `i`-th
iteration of the inner loop takes

```
n / 2^i
```

steps; the runtime bound of `O(n)` follows from the fact that the sum of denominators is the [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series), which converges to the constant `2`.

Comment: But doesn't the series -> 2 only as n -> ∞, in which the sum of the expression itself would be  ∞?

Comment: @KaranModi I'm not sure whether I understand your comment; the series converges _from below_, each single partial sum is smaller than `2`.

Comment: My mistake, the series indeed converges.